# Bash script - Need to monitor some process in linux system

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am writing this simply script which conver to into a daemon and run in the background. The script job is simple. And it need to monitor a process type say `ls` command process. And write it into a file for records.

My approach to this to just have a while true loop to constantly check for a process type using ps command. And if it detect it, it will append it to a file.

I was wondering if this is a bad approach to write this

my code as follow

```
while true
do 
   if [[ $(ps -aux | grep -w "ls") ]]
   then 
       #append to file
   fi 
done &
```

Comment: You may want to add a `sleep x` command lest your script go berserk. And, did you consider the `pgrep` command in lieu of the `ps | grep` pipe? Be aware you may get a multiline output.

Comment: yes. I have implement those. Also for the multi line output, i have implement a for loop to go through the ps output first and filter duplicate before append to a file.

Comment: Is that always the same process, or do PIDs change?

Comment: Yes Pid will change in this case. Since very ls command will have a start and end. And each time pid will  change which reflect on each ls command process

Answer (score 0):

You could

```
grep commandname /proc/*/comm
```

which, on my linux system, is a factor 2 - 3 faster than `ps | grep` or `pgrep`.

Comment: Ok but the whole while loop concept is correct right ? like i am just curious if there are any other way to monitor processes. Ihave tried watch command , but iti s not good in scripting.

Comment: @yolocoolflash what "process" are you talking about? It's beginning to sound like it should be a daemon instead.

Comment: It is a daemon which call this script and run it in the background

Comment: But the core function is in this while loop script which monitor a process type constantly

Answer (score 0):

You suggest,

> My approach to this to just have a while true loop to constantly check for a process type using ps command. And if it detect it, it will append it to a file.

If you're going to do that just search for the process name and append any match. (If there's no match, nothing will get output.)

```
while sleep 5
do
    ps -ef | grep -w '[l]s' >> matched.txt
done
```

Without knowing what you really want to achieve it's difficult to critique your approach. If you simply want to restart a process if it goes away, then consider using a `systemd` unit. If you want to record that a process exists you might be better off using `lastcomm` or another audit tool to capture the start and end times of the named process. In both cases you can abolish your busy loop and you'll not lose any short-lived process executions.

Comment: I am using systemd unit combine with this bash script to monitor a command process. So when a command process is being exited, then notify it .

Comment: yes  I need to create this project that monitor a passwd command process has been trigger by someone who login as root. As that operation or event is not where to be logged in any log file location.

Comment: That is why i create this little daemon script to monitor in the background. so it will keep monitor that command process for me.

Comment: "_I need to create this project that monitor a passwd command process has been trigger by someone who login as root._" is that what you want to do? There are far far easier and more reliable ways of doing that

Comment: "_systemd unit combine with this bash script to monitor a command process. So when a command process is being exited, then notify it_" why not have `systemd` tell you? It is the authoritative source of this information, and again there is then no need for this busy loop

Comment: May I know what is the way you prefer ? As I am out of idea . Thanks

Comment: I have able to use journalctl or in Ubuntu that will be Auth log location to keep monitor that file for and sudo passwd command